# Javascript array1 = array2, array2 = array3 then array1 = array3

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, equality

So I have this unwanted thing that keeps happening when I have **arary1** (which contains values that won't change throughout my javascript code) and then an exact copy (upon initialization) of a second **array2** that will contain the same variables but this time the numbers will change as the code goes. So if **array1 = array2** and **array2[x] = 2**, then **array1[x]** also gets the (**unwanted**) value of **2**. To escape this I used **for loops** but the code gets bigger and bigger. So what I came up with was an HTTP requesting a JSON file with jQuery in this case: **$.ajax({ ..type: get....url: www.location.com...datatype: 'json'....success: function {})** and in this **function** I had **array1 and array2** to receive the **same** data from the JSON file (not necessarily making array1 = array2 ????) so I got really disappointed when I found out that both arrays were being changed at the same time as if **array1 = array2**. So how can I avoid this? Or what am I doing here wrong? Or is there anything that I should know of?

Comment: Well `array1 = array2` doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Yes, ajax requests are definitely an overkill. JSON serialisation and deserialisation can help to make deep copies, but should not be necessary in general.